# Python & vscode: prob to import another module/package/class

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've some prob to setup my vscode project in python. I try to create a test to test my car module. But, I've always the error
no module found when I try to run ( test_whendrivecar.py)

test_whendrivecare inherited to context.context inherited to baseclasstest ( just some struct of GivenWhenThen test).

I tried to setup in sys.path(c:/users/me/drive) , but that doesn't work to run my test. I 've againt the error no module 'baseclasstest' found or no module 'car' found.

I 've same prob if I tried to create a module on same level that car directory.

here my project struc :

[image]

vscode 1.39.2
python 3.7.3
env: create by conda
test framework: unittest

what I tried:

- put the path  in settings.json "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" - > doesn't work
- put the path in launch.json "env": "PYTHONPATH":  -> doesn't work

can you help my ? I thought that is easy to use custom module/package in python.

- Ohhh I know, python 3.3+ doesn't need **init**.py I just put that to be sure.

I looking on google, but I don't found anything to help me.

Comment: How are you executing your tests? And what is the import statement you have in your test file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `from drive.car.car import "your class"` in your test